# Convergence for $\frac{1}{n} {\bf p}^H {\bf D}{\bf q}$ using law of large numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, random-variables, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose ${\bf p} = [p_1, \dots, p_n]^T$ and ${\bf q} = [q_1, \dots, q_n]^T$ be mutually independent $\mathbb{C}^{n \times 1}$ vectors whose elements are i.i.d zero-mean and unit variance random variable (RVs), i.e., $\mathbb{E}\{|p_i|^2\} = \mathbb{E}\{|q_i|^2\} = 1$. Then from law  of large numbers we have $\frac{1}{n} {\bf p}^H {\bf q} \to 0$.

Now let ${\bf D} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a diagonal matrix with different real entries, i.e., $d_{n}$. Then can I use law of large numbers to find convergence for:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{n} {\bf p}^H {\bf D}{\bf q}
\end{equation}

Comment: It depends on how $D$ depends on $n$.

Comment: Hi Kimchi. $D$ is a diagonal matrix with real entries in diagonal and each element is different. I think if the elements of $D$ are same we can directly use law of large numbers. But in this case the elements are different.

Comment: But how do the entries in $D$ change as $n$ changes? If the $k$th diagonal entry in $D$ is $k!$, for example, most of the oomph in your sum comes from the last term, and LLN behavior will not hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am interpreting the question as follows:

> Let $(d_{ij})_{i,j\in\mathbb N}$ be a deterministic doubly infinite
>   sequence. Let $(p_i)_{i,\in\mathbb N}$ and $(q_i)_{i,\in\mathbb N}$ be
>   independent iid sequences whose elements have mean $0$ and variance
>   $1$. Let $X_n=\sum_{i,j=1}^np_id_{ij}q_j$. Is it true that $\frac{X_n}{n}$ converges to $0$ in probability?

Before answering the question, I just want to point out that a routine calculation using independence of the $p_i$ and $q_j$ shows that that $\mathbb EX_n=0$ and 
$
\mathbb E[X_n^2]=\sum_{i,j=1}^nd_{ij}^2=\|D_n\|_2^2.
$
This shows that $n$ is the wrong scaling in the statement above, rather it should be $\|D_n\|_2^2$ in general (note that $\|D_n\|_2^2=n$ when $D_n$ is the identity matrix). For example, when $d_{ij}=1$ for all $i,j$ the quantity $X_n/n$ has infinite variance in the limit. In fact, in this case the variance of $X_n$ grows like $n^2$, not $n$, since we are summing $n^2$ independent quantities (unlike the case of the identity matrix, when there are only $n$).

Now let's answer the corrected version of the question.

> Let $X_n$ and $\|D_n\|_2$ be as above. Assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|D_n\|_2=\infty$. Then $\frac{X_n}{\|D_n\|_2^2}$ converges to $0$.

**Proof:**
By Chebyshev's inequality,
$$
\mathbb P\Bigl(\frac{X_n}{\|D_n\|_2^2}>\epsilon\Bigr)\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^2\|D_n\|_2^2}.
$$
By assumption, this tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, for all $\epsilon >0$, proving the claim.

Note, the assumption $\|D_n\|_2\to\infty$ is necessary. For example, if $d_{ij}=0$ whenever $i$ or $j>N$ then $X_n$ stays random in the $n\to\infty$ limit, so no convergence is possible.

**Note.** When $D_n$ is assumed to be a diagonal matrix, it may still not be the case that $\|D_n\|_2\to\infty$, for example if $d_{n,n}=n^{-2}$. Likewise, it can also be the case that $\|D_n\|_2$ grows asymptotically faster than $n$. So assuming the matrix is diagonal does not reduce the number of assumptions one has to make.

Comment: Hi. I just wanted to clarify a calculation based on your answer. So  I am now calculationg the value for $X = {\bf p}^H{\bf D}{\bf p}$. Now, based on your answer, $E[X] = \sum_i d_{i,i}$, where I have used the fact that ${\bf D}$ is a diagonal matrix. Now with $E[X] = \sum_i d_{i,i}$, can I claim $\frac{1}{n}{\bf p}^H{\bf D}{\bf p} \to \sum_i d_{i,i}$, as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: No, $\mathbb E[X_n]=0$ since the $p_i$ and $q_i$ have mean zero. It is essentially irrelevant whether $D_n$ is diagonal or not. And as I wrote above, normalizing using $n$ instead of $\|D_n\|_2^2$ means that the limit could either be $0$, or it could be $\infty$, or it could oscillate around in between and stay random.

Comment: Will $\mathbb{E}({\bf X}_n)$ be still be $0$ if ${\bf X}_n = {\bf p}^H {\bf D} {\bf p}$ instead of ${\bf X}_n = {\bf p}^H {\bf D} {\bf q}$, i.e., $\mathbb{E}[{\bf X}_n] = \mathbb{E}[ {\bf p}^H {\bf D} {\bf p}] = \mathbb{E}[\sum_i p_i^* d_{i,i} p_i] = \sum_i \mathbb{E}[|p_i|^2] d_{i,i} = \sum_i d_{i,i}$ given $\mathbb{E}[p_i^2] = 1$.

Comment: You are changing the question in the comments and it is hard to see (I misread your $q$ as a $p$ in the last comment). Just ask another question instead of doing this in the comments....

Comment: Hi thank you for the suggestion. I will post this clarification as a separate question.